# How to receive the debug messages in game?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm developing a multiplayer game using Godot 4.1.0. I found this extension to launch multiple instances with different parameters (I start 1 instance as host, and 2 others as clients): https://godotengine.org/asset-library/asset/2054

Unfortunately only one instance is available in the Editor debugger.
I made an in game console to log debug messages there.

How could I start a debug session for the other instances and receive the messages in the game, so I can debug while multiple instances are running?

Comment: There is no API for this as far as I know. There is a proposal, that I had a look into a while back: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/7328